# LiveData Observer not getting called

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a fragment and a corresponding viewmodel class. I get the list of contacts wrapped as LiveData from DB on the fragment`onActivityCreated` method. It works fine and i show the list of contacts using PagedListAdapter as Below:

```
var allContacts: LiveData<PagedList<Contact>>? = null
fun initData() {
    val factory = repo.getContacts()
    allContacts = LivePagedListBuilder(factory, PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setEnablePlaceholders(true)
            .setPageSize(Constant.CONTACT_LIST_PAGE_SIZE)
            .build()).build()
}
```

I have added an observer in my fragment as below:

```
viewModel.allContacts?.observe(this, Observer<PagedList<Contact>> {
        dataChanged()
    })
```

There is button in my fragment , which takes me to another screen , on that screen I add more contacts to table . But when I come back from that screen to my fragment , observer is not called . That means `dataChanged()` method is not getting called when I come back.

I know that, when I go to another activity from my fragment, the observer becomes inactive, but when I come back it becomes active again. So as per documentation:

> Generally, LiveData delivers updates only when data changes, and only to active observers. **An exception to this behaviour is that observers also receive an update when they change from an inactive to an active state**. Furthermore, if the observer changes from inactive to active a second time, it only receives an update if the value has changed since the last time it became active.

I was expecting the observer to be called , but its not . Am i missing something. I am using Room for my DB implementation.

Comment: Have you found any solution? Right now I am facing with same problem

Comment: found solution?

Comment: Observer also depend on ,how you are inserting data in room like if you are using repository method then it will invoke on change method but if you are using,
getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase().execSQL(anyQuery) to  change data in Room db then it will not called onchange methond of observer

Answer (score 0):

How do you create the model? Try to do it using the activity of the fragment instead of the fragment:

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activityOfYourFragment).get(YourViewModelClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating new viewModel instance, use activity view model. Below code will help you.

val model: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()